# Make an URL point to google maps app on Nokia (symbian)

Tags: google-maps, mobile, symbian, nokia

The iPhone has a functionality that when a google maps URL is typed into (or linked) the mobile browser it will open the Google Maps app instead of displaying it in the mobile browser.

Now I'm wondering if that same functionality exists for say a Nokia (Symbian) phone? Is there a way to set up the link to open the Google maps app on the Symbian phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at this related stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696252/how-can-i-open-my-application-by-default-if-i-click-a-url-through-browser-in-sym).

Comment: That clarified some of my question. It's not as simple or straightforward as i'd hoped. I won't get into it further at this point, no time left on this pet project.

Answer (score 1):

The Nokia Ovi Store does something similar, it pops up the store when you access a URL through the browser. I don't know *how* they do it though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... Let's take a look and see if I can dissect that link maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Not that straightforward or helpful in all cases, but at least in the latest Symbian^3, if you have Google Maps installed, pointing the browser to a .kml file (served with [correct MIME type](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#kml_server)) seems to open the file in Google Maps application automatically.